# SharePoint Alerts not working correctly

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, alert

I develop on SharePoint 2013 foundation. For some SharePoint list there is immediately created alert for special user. Alert created programmatically. User noticed about list items fields changing through email. So may question when list fields changed different times user receive email only for one change, why? For more information Immediately Alert timer job run after that fields changing. How to configure alert programmatically (C#) in order alert to work for two changes or there is another way?

Answer (score 0):

Sample code to create alert.

```
SPList list=web.Lists.TryGetList("Documents");
                    SPUser user = web.EnsureUser(@"domainName\user");
                    SPAlert newAlert = user.Alerts.Add();
                    newAlert.Title = "My Custom Alert";
                    newAlert.AlertType=SPAlertType.List;
                    newAlert.List = list;
                    newAlert.DeliveryChannels = SPAlertDeliveryChannels.Email;        
                    newAlert.EventType = SPEventType.Add;
                    newAlert.AlertFrequency = SPAlertFrequency.Immediate;                              
                    newAlert.Update();
```

Comment: So alert should be work for every event not only for Add. Did you understand my question?

Comment: Just sample code, for all events, use SPEventType.All  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.speventtype.aspx

Comment: Your sample code not connected with my question. So can you describe if item changed twice and corresponding Immediate Alert timer job run after that changes why user receive one for one change notification?